# Copy all files from one folder to another when there is no file with the same name but a different extension existing

Tags: linux

I have an IP-camera that saves its recordings to my Samba share. I want to copy those files to a different location once they are fully saved.

Now my problem is: the camera takes some time to copy the files in `.avi` format (named `motion-date.avi`) to my share, whilst it is doing so it also creates a `.idx` file (named `motion-date.idx`) of the same name, which will be deleted once it is done.

So I want to copy all `.avi` files, that don't have a corresponding `.idx` file, to a different folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find /source/dir/ -type f -name '*.avi' -exec sh -c 'test ! -f "${1%.*}.idx" && cp "$1" /target/dir/' sh {} \;
```

This command finds all `.avi` files under the `/source/dir/` and spawns a basic shell for every single one. The shell then tests if there isn't a corresponding `.idx` file and invokes `cp` when needed.

---

Edit: I changed the command a little bit to make it more foolproof. Upon the explicit request I explain the entire command in more detail.

- `find` – Find…
- `/source/dir/` – …in a given directory…
- `-type f` … …all the files…
- `-name '*.avi'` – …with names matching this pattern…
- `-exec` – …and for every single file found execute…
- `sh -c '…' sh {}` – …a shell that executes commands; inside the shell the path is available as `$1`, because `{}` gets substituted with the actual path to the particular file found (this is how `find -exec` works).
- `\;` – This indicates where the `-exec` ends.

Every shell gets `-c` option, which tells it to execute the next argument as it was a command typed. The command goes like this:

- `test` – Test and return exit status accordingly; the following arguments will tell what to test.

  - `!` – Caution: the test is reversed.
  - `-f` – Test if there's an existing file…
  - `"${1%.*}.idx"` – …under this path. The `${1%.*}` construct tells the shell to get the content of the parameter without the fragment from the last dot `.` to the end. I append another extension. This way I exchange them.
- `&&` – Only if the previous command (i.e. `test`) returned exit status `0`…
- `cp` – …copy…

  - `"$1"` – …the file that has been found by `find`…
  - `/target/dir/` – …to the target directory.

Final notes:

- I need a shell to take care of `"${1%.*}.idx"` and `&&`. If I wanted to copy every file found, then `… -exec cp {} /target/dir/ \;` would be enough (and yet far from optimal but let's not be distracted).
- It's good to quote (like with `""`) every path that *may* include spaces, special characters etc.
- The argument (command) to `sh` is single-quoted (`''`). If if was double-quoted (`""`) the expansion of `"${1%.*}.idx"` would occur in the current shell (the one that runs `find`) and this is not what I want. You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753).

Comment: Works perfectly. Where did you learn this?

Comment: @AhmedAkhtar I took no classes. You learn such things by working and playing with Linux, Bash etc. Not that I wrote this command instantly; it took me few minutes to compose, test and debug it. At some point you have enough experience to know that "this problem certainly can be solved with the tools I know, all I have to do is to make them work together".

Comment: I am quite fascinated by this command, it's really a piece of art. Can you explain it part by part in detail?

Comment: @AhmedAkhtar I have expanded my answer.

Comment: Amazing. I would have never thought to run another shell within find.